# Kendo DataSource Filtering with multiple conditions

Tags: datasource, kendo-ui

I want to build a filter for a datasource with multiple condition. I found this thread ([HERE](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/data-source/multiple-filters-on-datasource.aspx)) where the guys have almost the same problem, but me I want to make a OR and not a AND between my two operation.

There is the code I have so far :

```
        var filter = { logic: "OR", filters: [] };

        var filterProduct = { logic: "AND", filters: [] };
        var supplierValue = dropdownSupplier.value();
        if (supplierValue != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") {
            filterProduct.filters.push({ field: "SupplierId", operator: "eq", value: supplierValue });
        }

        var categoryValue = dropdownCategory.value();
        if (categoryValue != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") {
            filterProduct.filters.push({ field: "CategoryId", operator: "eq", value: categoryValue });
        }

        var typeValue = dropdownType.value();
        if (typeValue != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") {
            filterProduct.filters.push({ field: "TypeId", operator: "eq", value: typeValue });
        }


        var filterSelect = { logic: "OR", filters: [] };
        filterSelect.filters.push({ field: "Id", operator: "eq", value: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" });

        filter.filters.push(filterProduct);
        filter.filters.push(filterSelect);

        dropdownProduct.dataSource.query({ filter: filter });
```

In fact what I want to do it's to have : (filterProduct) OR (filterSelect) but if i'm not using "logic" in the variable filter, the filter will be an "AND".

Thanks alot

edit: There is a jsFiddle close to what I want to do but with the "AND" : [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/MG89G/) In this example the filter is : 
[ {[ Freight = 11.61 OR Freight = 51.30 ]} AND {[ City startswith "Charleroi" ]} ]

But I want to have somethign like : 
[ {[ Freight = 11.61 OR Freight = 51.30 ]} **OR** {[ City startswith "Charleroi" ]} ]

Comment: I finally got it, I will pu tmy code there in 8 hours when I will be able to... But the keyword AND and OR need to be lowercase and I don't need to use the variable filterSelect

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is the final code working properly :

The keyword AND and OR need to be lowercase and I don't need to use the variable filterSelect

> ```
>     var filter = { logic: "or", filters: [] };
>     var filterProduct = { logic: "and", filters: [] };
>     var supplierValue = dropdownSupplier.value();
>     if (supplierValue != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") {
>         filterProduct.filters.push({ field: "SupplierId", operator: "eq", value: supplierValue });
>     }
>     var categoryValue = dropdownCategory.value();
>     if (categoryValue != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") {
>         filterProduct.filters.push({ field: "CategoryId", operator: "eq", value: categoryValue });
>     }
>     var typeValue = dropdownType.value();
>     if (typeValue != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") {
>         filterProduct.filters.push({ field: "TypeId", operator: "eq", value: typeValue });
>     }
>     if (filterProduct.filters.length > 0) {
>         filter.filters.push(filterProduct);
>     }
>     filter.filters.push({ field: "Id", operator: "eq", value: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" });
>     dropdownProduct.dataSource.query({ filter: filter });
> ```

Answer (score 8):

Thanks forumma, your example helped me. For others trying to decipher the Kendo UI (since there are multiple, undocumented ways to do things), I have included my example to set filters on two different fields and one field has a compound OR filter:

```
var initialFilter = { logic: "or", filters: [] };
var filterStatus = [
    { field: "impStatus", operator: "neq", value: "Complete" }
    ];
var filterDeveloper = { logic: "or", filters: [
      { field: "developer", operator: "eq", value: "Unassigned" }
    ] };

filterDeveloper.filters.push( { field: "developer", operator: "eq", value: "Bob" } );

initialFilter.filters.push( filterStatus );
initialFilter.filters.push( filterDeveloper );

dataSource.filter( initialFilter );
```

Comment: This is very useful , I am trying to make my grid do something like this (ParentTrackingID = NULL) and 
(TargetFlight startsWith "Px" Or TargetFlight startsWith "Sx" or TargetFlight = NULL) and 
(OrganizationStatus eq "Approved" OR OrganizationStatus = "Updated")  and Ideas, does the initial filter have to have a logic ?